# Search YouTube API without login in

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I'm creating an app where i would like to display video result from the YouTube site.
However, i do not want the user to register for this.

After i registered my app, and allowed "YouTube Data Api", Still when i'm calling from my app:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=3&order=relevance&q=test&regionCode=AR&type=video&key={MyKey}

I'm getting back "forbidden (403)"

This issue suppose to be really simple, but i'm really straggling to get this to work, i'm thinking maybe it has something to do with the new API version 3.0, that you can not search without authentication?

Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Did you want only the Titles of you tube videos while searching by keyword..or anything else.@PiratM

Comment: @Vidhyanand I'm would like to get a list with the titles and URL's of the search results

Comment: You what to use Version 3 only of YOUTUBE API..or may be version 2.0(no problem) for searching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below URL for searching of youtube videos using version3

[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=nokialumia&key=@"API _KEY"&maxResults=20&pageToken=0](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=nokialumia&key=@%22API%20_KEY%22&maxResults=20&pageToken=0)

For suggestions of you tube videos you can use below link. It will gives you the data in XML format. You can parse and get results.

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&ds=yt&q=nokialumia

If you want to use Version 2 use below link

[Youtube Search using version 2.0](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/fun?v=2&alt=jsonc&start-index=26)

Hope it helps you...!

Comment: Thanks you! I used the version 2.0, just fix it a bit, took of the "/-/fun" And aded "Q=" and the search parameter, so it looks like so: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/?&v=2&alt=jsonc&start-index=1&q=Smells%20like%20teen"

Answer (score 0):

What kind of results do you want to see? Views, comments, share, likes? I think that you are not able to see any results by Youtube Data Api or Youtube Analytics API V3 without a valid key. You can find all error codes and their meanings from [this link.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would like to see a list of titles and URL's of the search results. I do have a valid key, and the link does not help..

Comment: You're welcome. You should be able to use your own credentials to make those requests. Are you familiar with Oauth2 ? Because one key is not enough for you to login on V3.

Comment: Yah i'm familiar with Oauth, and as far as i know all the point if it is to ask the user to confirm log in, and that is not what i'm looking for.. So your saying there is no way of Using the YouTube api without login?